# How to assign output of shell command to Makefile variable for all make targets?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have a random string that is generated and used for multiple make targets. My `Makefile` looks like:

```
VALUE := $(shell strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 30 | tr -d '\n')

target_0:
  echo ${VALUE}
  $(MAKE) target_1

target_1:
  echo ${VALUE}
```

I would like `VALUE` to be the same among all targets (set it once and refer to its value throughout the file), but with my current implementation I get the following (values are different):

```
K29p6whTYtrNIrzkaNkF75qtc2YQEq
hcXH00hzYMRa36hp55wBKCRH0YfJvp
```

How can I set `VALUE` at the top of the `Makefile` so that it is only evaluated and set once for all targets and not every time a target is called?

Comment: `$(MAKE) target_1` is a recursive make invocation.

Comment: @jamieguinan Yes, I am using it to "call" one target from another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(MAKE) target_1` is a recursive make invocation, whole new `make` process that reads `Makefile` from the top.

If you really want to do that, you could pass `VALUE=${VALUE}` to the recursive make, and it will take precedence over the `:=` assignment,

```
        $(MAKE) target_1 VALUE=${VALUE}
```

As an alternative to recursion, you could use dependencies to invoke one rule after the other,

```
target_0: target_1
         ...
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks; if it is not the best practice to use a recursive make invocation, what should I be doing instead to call one target from another?

Comment: There's the "recursive make considered harmful" crowd, and there are good arguments for that perspective, but I use it sometimes nonetheless. I'll edit the answer to suggest an alternative.